# Webpack module parse failed warning with .svg files and custom config

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, svg, webpack

I'm using Webpack in my React/Rails application. My team uses `.svg` images in parts of our app.

We have two primary use-cases for them.

1. Using SVGs as background images within our stylesheets (we use `.scss`).
2. Using SVGs within React components, with a tool called [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/) which transforms SVGs into React components.

Therefore, we have the following configuration set up in our `config/webpack/environment.js` file ([Rails' Webpack integration](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) uses this unusual scheme for Webpack configuration):

```
const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker")
const fileLoader = environment.loaders.get("file")
const babelLoader = environment.loaders.get("babel")

// ... other stuff

environment.loaders.insert("svg", {
  test: /\.svg$/,
  issuer: { test: /\.jsx?$/ },
  use: babelLoader.use.concat([
    "@svgr/webpack"
  ])
}, { after: "file" })

fileLoader.exclude = /\.(svg)$/i

environment.loaders.insert("scss svg", {
  test: /\.svg$/,
  issuer: { test: /\.scss?$/ },
  use: ["file-loader"]
}, { after: "svg" })

// ... more other stuff

module.exports = environment
```

Then, we get the following error in our Webpack build:

```
WARNING in ./app/javascript/shared/svg/Phone.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

The strange thing is, the configuration actually works as is for both use cases I described.

As you can see, we are using the [`issuer` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleissuer) in the loader configuration, which instructs Webpack on which loader to use depending upon which file type is doing the `import` of an SVG.

I'm wondering if there are any Webpack experts who could explain why Webpack still issues this warning, even though there *are* in fact loaders configured to handle the file type, and also when there is no "real" problem in the output bundles (no runtime errors or broken images).

Thanks!

Comment: What file(s) imports the Phone.svg?

Comment: There are a couple in our app. They are both `.jsx` files

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to solve it, but I know what's happening.

At some point you're doing a dynamic import with a template parameter. This parameter is loose enough that it's matching your .svg files. This means webpack will make those svgs entry points because it doesn't know whether you will match them or not. Because they are entries, they have no issuer.

I don't know if there's a way to specify a loader with *no* issuer. However, if you try making your template string in the dynamic import a bit more strict so it cannot match the svgs, you'll find the warning goes away.